# SMART test failures on harddrive

Tags: hard-drive, smart

i have probably problem on my system with SMART failures on my harddrive.

There is used OS: SLES 11.2 i586.

Problem is, that recently there appeared some errors in SMART print of status of my device (*smartctl -a /dev/sda*) i am attaching.

I am interested what mean errors mentioned in last half of print with error messages (*Error: ABRT*, etc.), if it represents any serious error, or what should be wrong with this drive.

I have tried to run smart test manually with *smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda*, i have tried also short, but data output of *smartctl -a* didnt changed after test.

Please advise.

Thank you for response.

Im am attaching print of *smartctl -a /dev/sda*:

```
smartctl 5.39 2008-10-24 22:33 [i686-suse-linux-gnu] (openSUSE RPM)
Copyright (C) 2002-8 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST250DM000-1BD141
Serial Number:    XYZ
Firmware Version: FJK2
User Capacity:    250,059,350,016 bytes
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4
Local Time is:    Fri Sep  4 12:38:28 2020 GST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                 ( 600) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  45) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x303f) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   112   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       47240608
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       167
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   087   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       626039220
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   029   029   000    Old_age   Always       -       62401
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       167
183 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       4295032833
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   072   066   045    Old_age   Always       -       28 (Lifetime Min/Max 27/32)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   028   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       28 (0 21 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   034   024   000    Old_age   Always       -       47240608
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       270179212784577
241 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       527260569
242 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3380033686

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 1
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 50640 hours (2110 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 51 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff   1d+00:27:00.197  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  b0 d4 00 81 4f c2 00 00   1d+00:26:52.471  SMART EXECUTE OFF-LINE IMMEDIATE
  b0 d1 01 01 4f c2 00 00   1d+00:26:52.407  SMART READ ATTRIBUTE THRESHOLDS [OBS-4]
  b0 d0 01 00 4f c2 00 00   1d+00:26:52.379  SMART READ DATA
  b0 da 00 00 4f c2 00 00   1d+00:26:52.362  SMART RETURN STATUS

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short captive       Interrupted (host reset)      90%     50640         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     50640         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error at 50640 hours occurred because the computer was shut down or rebooted while the test was in progress. This is why it is shown as "Interrupted (host reset)". It says nothing about the state of your hard drive.